# Get array sting numbers from array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an 'animals' array stored in the database like this:

```
array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Bird"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Cat"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Zebra"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "Fish"
    [4]=>
    string(7) "Hamster"
}
```

...which I can return on the front-end like this...

```
<?php $animals = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'animals', true ); ?>

<ul>
    <?php
        foreach ( $animals as $animal) { ?>
            <li><?php echo $animal; ?></li>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

...and displays like this:

- Bird
- Cat
- Zebra
- Fish
- Hamster

But what I need to also do, is display the sting number next to each animal, so the result would look like this:

- Bird (0)
- Cat (1)
- Zebra (2)
- Fish (3)
- Hamster(4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the array using key value syntax.

```php
<ul>
    <?php
        foreach($array as $key=>$value) { ?>
            <li><?php echo $value . " (" . $key . ")"; ?></li>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
}
```